# Upload audio, video and image using FileBody

Tags: android, image, audio, video, file-upload

I want to upload audio, video and image together. I am using the following code:

```
if (file_name_for_rear_image != null && f_intruder_rear.exists()) {
    ContentType contentType = ContentType.create("image/jpeg");
    FileBody cbFile = new FileBody(f_intruder_rear,contentType);
    multipartEntity.addPart("image[]", cbFile);
}
File video_file = new File(VIDEO_PATH_NAME);
if (VIDEO_PATH_NAME != null && video_file.exists()) {
    ContentType contentType = ContentType.create("video/mp4");
    FileBody cbFile = new FileBody(video_file,contentType);
    multipartEntity.addPart("video", cbFile);
}
File audio_file = new File(audio_file_name);
if (audio_file_name != null && audio_file.exists()) {
    ContentType contentType = ContentType.create("audio/mp3");
    FileBody cbFile = new FileBody(audio_file, contentType);
    multipartEntity.addPart("audio", cbFile);
}
```

For Image - When I reomve content-type from image filebody, it's getting uploaded. But when I add content-type, it's not working.

For audio/video - No matter if I keep content-type or not, it's not getting uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by passing filename in `FileBody` object.

```
if (file_name_for_rear_image != null && f_intruder_rear.exists()) {

        ContentType contentType = ContentType.create("image/jpeg");
        FileBody cbFile = new FileBody(f_intruder_rear, contentType,
                "image.jpg");
        multipartEntity.addPart("image[]", cbFile);
    }
    File video_file = new File(VIDEO_PATH_NAME);
    if (VIDEO_PATH_NAME != null && video_file.exists()) {
        ContentType contentType = ContentType.create("video/mp4");
        FileBody cbFile = new FileBody(video_file, contentType, "video.mp4");
        multipartEntity.addPart("video", cbFile);
    }
    File audio_file = new File(audio_file_name);
    if (audio_file_name != null && audio_file.exists()) {
        ContentType contentType = ContentType.create("audio/mp3");
        FileBody cbFile = new FileBody(audio_file, contentType, "audio.mp3");
        multipartEntity.addPart("audio", cbFile);
    }
```

You can give any file name. Hope it helps someone else because i struggled too much to found this.

Comment: Man, I LOVE YOU, I spent hours on trying to solve this!

Comment: I am glad I could help you :)